# (iPhone/iOS) UISearchBar Scope Buttons cover first row of UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, button, scope, uisearchbar

I know this question has been asked before, but I have yet to find a true solution. I have a `UITableView` with a `UISearchBar` as its `tableHeaderView.` Whenever the scope buttons appear, they cover the first row of the `UITableView`.

I have tried using `UITableView.contentOffset` to offset the `UITableView` by the height of the scope buttons, and this works until the user taps the `UITableView` or scrolls it, at which point the `UITableView` jumps back to its original offset.

The best I've been able to do is set the `UISearchBar` as a separate item in the view, and simply resize the `UITableView` dynamically to show or hide it when the user taps a search button. The only problem is that there is no animation, so the transition is sharp.

UPDATE: I solved the problem by implementing a `UISearchDisplayController`, as this was the cleanest and easiest solution to work with. The `UISearchDisplayController` automatically shows/hides the scope buttons and moves the `UITableView` down accordingly. I didn't do this at first because I wanted the `UITableView` to remain visible rather than initially being blacked out by the `UISearchDisplayController`, however I've come to realize that the blackout does not hinder any functionality; the user would not have initiated a search if he wanted to continue looking at the `UITableView` the way it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideas:

- Set the `tableHeaderView` to a `UIView` that has the `UISearchBar` as its subview, and resize that `UIView` when the scope buttons appear.  The `UITableView` will hopefully respond to that view changing its frame.
- Set the `UISearchBar` as the content of the first cell of the `UITableView` and use `(void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation` when the scope buttons hide or show.  Return the proper height to have the cell animate to its new height.

Or you could use the method you describe (`UISearchBar` as a separate item in the view), and use an animation block to animate the transition so it's less sharp.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^
  {
     //change table view frame here
  }];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you adjust the cell height of the header based on if the search controller is active or not, all works well

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    var headerHeight: CGFloat = 0.0

    if searchController.isActive
    {
        headerHeight = searchController.searchBar.frame.size.height
    }

    return headerHeight
}
```